# MongoDB unknown operator: $or error for properly formatted query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

My query is as such:

```
const users = this.mongo.db.collection('Users')
let query = { '$or': [ { "email": {'$eq': req.body.email }}, {"username": {'$eq': req.body.username }} ] }
users.findOne({query}, function(err, result) {
...
```

Not really sure why it isn't working. To my understanding, this is the correct way of formatting an `or`?

Comment: `users.findOne(query, function(err, result) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong at third line `{query}` => `query`

```
db.collection.find({
  "$or": [
    {
      "email": {
        "$eq": "222"
      }
    },
    {
      "username": {
        "$eq": "Tom"
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NT9y2Aj0tr7)